# Custom Admin Plugin - Injecting repeatable select fields (add, remove) into an Ordered List

Tags: plugin-development

I'm currently creating my first plugin; I came a long way; although I've stumbled upon a problem.

1. I don't know what's the right way of actually creating fields in wordpress - if there's any validation, if there's security to be added such as nonce etc.
2. My *current problem*: I've noticed a weird behaviour, when I inject a repeatable form field into a form and I submit the form I don't see the data for the injected ones, even though they're identical in the DOM. - Although when I do add more in the document (without injecting the form field) I get the data submitted together with the form.

**Form**

```
<form id='new-form' action="" method="post">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="AUTO_GENERATED" disabled></td>                
    <td>
        <select name="new-placement" id="new-placement">
            <option value="val">slug</option>
        </select>
    </td>               
    <td><input type="text" id="new-slug" name="new-slug"></td>
    <td>
        <ol id="list-container-new">
            <li>
                <select name="new-items[]">
                   <option value="val">name</option>
                </select>
                <button class="remove-item-new">Remove</button>
            </li>                       
        </ol>                  

        <button id="add-item-to-items-new">Add</button>             
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( "items_save", "items_save") ?>
        <button id="newsubmit" name="newsubmit" type="submit">Create</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

**jQuery to add**

```
    jQuery('#add-item-to-list-new').on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();     

        let html = '<li>';
        html += '<select name="new-items[]">';
        itemsVariable.forEach((element, index, arr) => {
            html += '<option value="' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</option>';         
        }); 
        html += '</select>';
        html += '<button class="remove-item-new">Remove</button>';
        html += '</li>'

        jQuery('#list-container-new').append(html);
    })
```

The above doesn't get submitted together with the form data; although if I do add it manually in the page, it does. - Is there a step I'm skipping? such as telling wordpress that I'm adding a new field?

Comment: Can you show your form code? And are you sure the `select`'s `name` (`new-items[]`) is correct? And have you confirmed that the `#list-container-new` is actually in the form? Try to inspect the generated source.

Comment: @SallyCJ yes, it's correct, and it's actually added to the list, and I can see it; although not submitted. - Sure will update question with form code.

Comment: @SallyCJ updated; it seems like when injected; something is trashing it on the way to submit. - Weird behaviour.

Comment: I'm actually referring to the full `form` element (`<form>...</form>`). But it's possible there's a script which alters the form data upon submitting. Try to find that script/code?

Comment: I don't believe I have any except for Wordfence et cetera. - Sure let me add the form.

Comment: Disabled all plugins - same thing... O_o I think wordpress might have some security for this..

Comment: I think I've found the issue; which I was never aware of. (hence why I'm not a front end dev): A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr. Attempting to put one there will tend to cause the browser to move the form to it appears after the table (while leaving its contents — table rows, table cells, inputs, etc — behind).

You can have an entire table inside a form. You can have a form inside a table cell. You cannot have part of a table inside a form.

Comment: Fixed... thanks @SallyCJ

Comment: Okay, but seems like there's a typo: `<button id="add-item-to-items-new">` - should be `<button id="add-item-to-list-new">`, I guess.. And yes, you're missing the `<table>` and `</table>` tags there.. although Chrome for example would actually just "forgive"/auto-correct/"un-`table`" that.. (i.e. ignore the `tr` and `td` tags)

Comment: Yes I didn't add them to the snippet and the `button` spelling is in the example because I had to change the names here because of disclosure. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

> A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr.
>   Attempting to put one there will tend to cause the browser to move the
>   form to it appears after the table (while leaving its contents — table
>   rows, table cells, inputs, etc — behind).
>
> You can have an entire table inside a form. You can have a form inside
>   a table cell. You cannot have part of a table inside a form.
>
> Use one form around the entire table. Then either use the clicked
>   submit button to determine which row to process (to be quick) or
>   process every row (allowing bulk updates).

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table/5967613).